# File won't copy to Docker file?

Tags: bash, docker, qgis, synology

I run this file (partial) under "root" account on my Synology.
but it won't start, in my error log I got this message:

**[FATAL tini (9)] exec /home/qgis/cmd.sh failed: No such file or directory**

Can someone help me please...

This is the part where cmd.sh is added:

```
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.19.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

ENV QGIS_PREFIX_PATH /usr
ENV QGIS_SERVER_LOG_STDERR 1
ENV QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 2

COPY cmd.sh /home/qgis/cmd.sh
RUN chmod -R 777 /home/qgis/cmd.sh
RUN chown qgis:qgis /home/qgis/cmd.sh

USER qgis
WORKDIR /home/qgis

ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]

CMD ["/home/qgis/cmd.sh"]
create a file cmd.sh with this content:
```

*This is the cmd.sh file:*

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $DEBUG == "1" ]] && env

exec /usr/bin/xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -p 5555 -n -d /home/qgis -- /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
```

Comment: Where do you run the docker file? `COPY ./cmd.sh /home/qgis/cmd.sh` Is the cmd.sh in your current folder ?

Comment: I'm asking what's the current folder in your terminal.

Comment: What base image do you start `FROM` (do you actually have GNU bash in your image)?  Is it possible that the script file could have DOS line endings?  Is it possible that some other unprivileged user has overwritten the script (`chmod 0777` is almost always a security-related error)?

Comment: FROM debian:bullseye-slim

Comment: In Visual Studio Code I  can see that my file uses CRLF, good point thank you, I will build the Docker file again, I come back later...